# Binding GridView ItemsSource and SelectedItem to generic types

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I am using Silverlight 4, RIA Service, MEF and MVVM.

I am trying to create a system configuration update page so i can easily update my lookup tables.
I have a RadGridView with which I wish to display and add new records from multiple entities.
I want to use the following:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GenericEntityList, Mode=TwoWay}"

SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedEntity, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Since I want to make the GridView writeable, I cannot bind ItemsSource to CollectionViewSource.View -as I have done in other instances where my gridview is ReadOnly.
I want to have GenericEntityList be an ObservableCollection or List of unknown Entity type until i make a selection of a given Entity type. 
For example, if i want to edit Sales and Products with this same grid, how can i defer making GenericEntityType of type  or  until AFTER i choose Sales or Product?

A long way to do this is to dynamically add the ItemsSource and SelectedItem properties in the codebehind. The problem is I have about 25 different entities and this will be 'untidy' for want of a better word.

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read up on the dynamic keyword e.g.

```
ObservableCollection<dynamic> dynamicList = new ObservableCollection<dynamic>();
```

However, I'm not sure whether all third party grids support binding to dynamic data.  Alternatively, could your lookup objects not implement a generic interface?